# PhoneGap Parse JS logout function returns 404

Tags: javascript, cordova, parse-platform

I am developing a PhoneGap + Parse application.

I have a login page and a logout button. I call the following code on logout button click.

```
$('#signout').click(function(event){
  $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#signin", { reload:true, transition:'flow', changeHash:true });

  Parse.User.logOut();
  console.log('logged out');

});
```

I get the following message in my browser console.

```
POST http://192.168.2.2:3000/proxy/https%3A%2F%2Fapi.parse.com%2F1%2Flogin 404 (Not Found)
```

What does this mean? What should be corrected for the logout functionality to work properly?

Comment: platform? cordova CLI version? cordova platform version?

Comment: I used phonegap exe to setup the project

Comment: phonegap exe? what is that?

Comment: Its a windows desktop application i used to create the project boilerplate code

Comment: you mean phonegap desktop app?

Comment: and login works fine? you just get that error on logout?

Comment: Yes. I am able to login, sign up user. But logout gives me this error

Comment: I don't know what is happening in your app, but usually login gives 404 error when user is not found. But you called logout..

Comment: Now when I intended the code snippet correctly I can see you enter singin page with forced reload of page. Does that page itself somehow clear session on start and when the code reaches logout, there is no more user to sign out?

Comment: @mico I dont think so. Because when I restart the phonegap server or open the url from a browser after closing it, parse still has the user logged in. I suppose thats how parse works.

Comment: Can you please post your js file with login and sign up code snippet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re the POST for a login....

I think you want your framework ( jquery/cordova ) to issue a GET not a POST.

in addition the GET is going to require the following Headers and parms

```
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: AbR" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: uI9" \
  -H "X-Parse-Revocable-Session: 1" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'username=e6' \
  --data-urlencode 'password=e8'
```

above from parse , REST manual applies to what you have on the WIRE via http protocol and in your console log.

So, in your framework code, prior to whatever issues the get, you would need to urlEncode both the username , password values.

Then append the query string below..

```
?username=$encodedNameVal&password=$encodedPasswrdVal
```

to the end of the Domain/path you are passing to GET...

```
api.parse.com/1/login
```

not familiar with PG , but i dont need to be in order to interpret the 404 u have.

Comment: Re your framework and devel/debug... You are going to want to track NET request in your console/devTools and to realize that the framework should be issuing http commands to parse.com that you can parallel over at any CURL/WGET CLI.  if you have a module that logsout/logsin you may want to fire up those respective REST commands on the CLI , watch them working / OR NOT. and then look for their likeness being issued by your runtime framework.. It can help understand your apps at a critical , low level you must have command of for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#signout').click(function (event) {
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#signin", {
        reload : true,
        transition : 'flow',
        changeHash : true,
        beforechange : function (event, ui) {
            Parse.User.logOut();
            console.log('logged out');
        }
    });
});
```

Haven't tested this but using beforechange might help you logout from Parse and then transitions the page to signin.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#signout').on('click',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  Parse.User.logOut();
  $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#signin", { reload:true, transition:'flow', changeHash:true });
  console.log('logged out');
});
```